# Inputting the variable answer more than once exits the whole program

Tags: c

Context: I am trying to make a number guessing program for my class. The program is supposed to generate random numbers from 1 - 100 and if its too small, I press '>' to get to a smaller number, or I can press '<' to get a higher random number, etc. **My problem is that if I input '<', '>', or a combination of them more than once into scanf, my program just exits instead of finding another lower/higher number.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void main(void)
{
   int randomGen, num;
   char answer;

   printf("Choose a number between 1 and 100, I will try to guess the number correctly.\n");
   printf("If the number is too low, press >. If the number is too high, press <.\n");
   printf("If the guess is correct, press =.\n\n");

   srand(time(0));
   randomGen = rand()%(100 + 1 - 1) + 1;
   num = randomGen;
   printf("%d\n", num);
   scanf("%s", &answer);

   if (answer == '>')
   {
       randomGen = rand()%(num + 1 - 1) + 1;
       printf("%d\n", randomGen);
       scanf("%s", &answer);
   }

   else if (answer == '<')
   {
       randomGen = rand()%(100 + 1 - num) + num;
       printf("%d\n", randomGen);
       scanf("%s", &answer);
   }

   else if (answer == '=')
   {
       printf("Thank you for using my program.\n");
       exit(0);
   }

   else
   {
       printf("Please use the correct sign, Exiting Program.\n");
       exit(0);
   }

}
```

Expected Result Example:

48
>
30
>
(some number lower than 30)

What happens in the Program:
[!code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaroK.png)

Comment: Since you read null-terminated strings into a single `char` you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and tend to the warnings

Comment: Although this is not relevant, you may want to put the random number generataion logic in a loop.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why ` + 1 - 1`? The compiler will very likely optimize that away.

Comment: If you want to repeat actions you need a loop but you don't have it. And it looks a bit harsh to me to exit the program on a wrong input. Why not just warn (what you do already) and ignore it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not sure why it's + 1 - 1, I looked up a way to set a range for rand() and that's what I found and it works and could you explain null-terminated strings further?

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop in your code, here it just executes and then leaves.

Something like :

```
int done = 0;

while (done != 1) {
     scanf(...)

     if (smth) 
         do smth
     else if (smth_else)
         do smth
     [...]
     else if (char == '=')
         done = 1;

}
return 0
```